# Problema con consulta a mysql desde java

Tags: java, mysql

Primero hago un registro a la base de datos desde un Frame y sin salir de la aplicacion ingreso a otro Frame donde hago la consulta de los datos pero el dato que recien ingrese desde el Frame anterior no aparece, si cierro el programa y lo vuelvo a ejecutar e ingreso directo a el Frame de las consultas si me aparece el registro, este es el codigo que utilizo para hacer la consulta.

```
 try {
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
    final JTable table = new JTable(modelo);
    TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        modelo.addColumn(columnas[i]);
    }
    columnModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(70);
    columnModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(120);
    columnModel.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(30);
    columnModel.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(30);

    DefaultTableCellRenderer tcr = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    tcr.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(tcr);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(tcr);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(tcr);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(tcr);

    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(400,300));
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);

    Connection con = getConection();
    String sql = "SELECT num_control,Nombre,fecha_inicio,fecha_termino FROM alumno";
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    ResultSetMetaData rsMd = rs.getMetaData();
    int cantidadColumnas = rsMd.getColumnCount();

    while(rs.next()) {
        Object[] filas = new Object[cantidadColumnas];
        for(int i=0; i<cantidadColumnas;i++) {
            filas[i]=rs.getObject(i+1); 
        }
        modelo.addRow(filas);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

cuando se realiza cambios a los datos del modelo de la tabla debes disparar que el cambio se dio para que la Interfaz de usuario Refleje esos cambios. 
esto se logra mediante el uso de el siguiente metodo del Table model: `modelo.fireTableDataChanged();`

este metodo debe ser llamado cuando ya se termino de actualizar los datos a la tabla.
ver: 
[Javadoc de AbstractTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged%28%29)

Comment: Ya lo coloque pero sigue sin actualizar los datos

Comment: intenta ademas agregar `modelo.fireTableStructureChanged();` si esto no funciona debe ser por que esas variables no estan siendo utilizadas o agregadas al UI, en cuyo caso requiero un demo funcional compatible con el estandar [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) para poder determinar que exactamente esta mal.