# consulta desde java a mysql

Tags: java

Primero hago un registro a la base de datos desde un Frame y sin salir de la aplicacion ingreso a otro Frame donde hago la consulta de los datos pero el dato que recien ingrese desde el Frame anterior no aparece, si cierro el programa y lo vuelvo a ejecutar e ingreso directo a el Frame de las consultas si me aparece el registro, este es el codigo que utilizo para hacer la consulta.

```
 try {
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
    final JTable table = new JTable(modelo);
    TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        modelo.addColumn(columnas[i]);
    }
    columnModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(70);
    columnModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(120);
    columnModel.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(30);
    columnModel.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(30);

    DefaultTableCellRenderer tcr = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    tcr.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(tcr);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(tcr);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(tcr);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(tcr);

    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(400,300));
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);

    Connection con = getConection();
    String sql = "SELECT num_control,Nombre,fecha_inicio,fecha_termino FROM alumno";
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    ResultSetMetaData rsMd = rs.getMetaData();
    int cantidadColumnas = rsMd.getColumnCount();

    while(rs.next()) {
        Object[] filas = new Object[cantidadColumnas];
        for(int i=0; i<cantidadColumnas;i++) {
            filas[i]=rs.getObject(i+1); 
        }
        modelo.addRow(filas);
    }
```

Comment: Por lo que se puede observar tu agregas el registro a la base de datos desde el jFrame pero no tienes un evento que vuelva a refrezcar tu tabla una vez realizado esto. Mi sugerencia es que desacoples tu codigo. Ademas deberias tener un algoritmo que vuelva a llamar la base de datos y llene nuevamente la tabla.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Problema con consulta a mysql desde java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/216764/problema-con-consulta-a-mysql-desde-java)